# $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} k(1+\cos(2k \pi x)) \chi_{(-1/2k,1/2k)}$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

How do I calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k(x)
=\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} k(1+\cos(2k \pi x)) \chi_{\left(\frac{-1}{2k},\frac{1}{2k}\right)}$$

Comment: Limit in what sense? (Probably in the sense of distributions, just making sure.) The fractions are meant to be $\pm \frac{1}{2k}$?

Comment: Yes. In the distribution sense

Comment: what is $\chi$?

Comment: the characteristic function. So it is equal to one in the given interval and 0 elsewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compute the limit, take a test function $\varphi$ and integrate:

$$\int_{-\frac{1}{2k}}^{\frac{1}{2k}} k(1+\cos (2\pi kx))\varphi(x)\,dx
= k\int_{-\frac{1}{2k}}^{\frac{1}{2k}}\varphi(x)\,dx + \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\cos (2\pi y)\varphi\left(\frac{y}{k}\right)\,dy.$$

The first integral tends to $\varphi(0)$, and the second to

$$\varphi(0)\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \cos (2\pi y)\,dy = \varphi(0) \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\sin \pi - \sin (-\pi)\right) = 0,$$

so $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} g_k = \delta$.

Comment: So I compute the fourier transformation of g and found $\hat{g}(y)=\frac{ik}{y}+k[\frac{sin(1/k(2 \pi k-iy))}{2k \pi -iy} +\frac{sin(1/k(2 \pi k+iy))}{2k \pi +iy}$ so how would I take the limit? Would it be the same as this progress or will it be like a normal limit?

Comment: In principle, the same process, but often you can take short-cuts, using limits you already know. For example, if I parse it correctly, you can write the second and third term like $$\frac{\sin (2\pi \pm iy/k)}{2\pi \pm iy/k} = \pm\frac{\sin (iy/k)}{2\pi \pm iy/k},$$ and use the uniform convergence of $\sin (iy/k) = i\sinh (y/k)$ to $0$ on compact sets to conclude that those tend to $0$.

Comment: But lim $\frac{ik}{y}=\infty$

Comment: Indeed. The $\frac{1}{y}$ should be interpreted as a principal value integral, $$\operatorname{v.p.}\int \frac{\varphi(y)}{y}\,dy,$$ but with the $k$ factor, it doesn't converge. Possibly you miscomputed the Fourier transform? Let me check.

Comment: Using $\hat{f}(y) = \int f(x) e^{-2\pi i xy}\,dx$ as the Fourier transform, I get $$\hat{g}_k(y) = \frac{\sin \frac{\pi y}{k}}{\frac{\pi y}{k}} + \frac{\sin \pi\left(1+\frac{y}{k}\right)}{2\pi\left(1+\frac{y}{k}\right)} + \frac{\sin \pi\left(1-\frac{y}{k}\right)}{2\pi\left(1-\frac{y}{k}\right)}$$ as the Fourier transform. The first term tends to $1$.

Comment: So my fourier transformation is wrong?

Comment: Since $g_k$ is even, only the real part of $e^{-2\pi i xy}$ contributes, and since $g_k$ is real, its Fourier transform is therefore also real (and even).